# Form is being submitted despite being invalid during unit testing with jest - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to test a component that submits a form:

- The component requires an 'onSubmit' function.
- It includes an input field with the type set to 'email'.
  When I try to submit an invalid email, the browser prevents the submission and displays an error message:
  [browser preventing me from submitting an invalid email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upVB7.png)
  However, when I replicate the same actions in my test, it fails because the mocked 'onSubmit' function is being called even when the email is invalid (the 'onSubmit' function shouldn't be called).
  Below is a condensed version of both my component and the Jest test I am using
  Component:

```
interface AppProps {
  onSubmit: () => Promise<any>;
  onComplete: (data: any) => void;
}

function App(props: AppProps) {
  function handleSubmit(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit().then((response) => {
      props.onComplete(response);
    });
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email"> Email </label>
      <input id="email" type="email" required />
      <button> Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

test("Invalid form isn't submitted", async () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();
  onSubmit.mockResolvedValue("");

  const onComplete = jest.fn((value) => {
    console.log("Function called");
  });

  render(<App onSubmit={onSubmit} onComplete={onComplete} />);

  const input = screen.getByLabelText("Email");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "invalid" } });

  const button = screen.getByText("Submit");  
  fireEvent.click(button);

  expect(onSubmit).not.toBeCalled();
});
```

This is the output of npm run test
FAIL  src/App.test.tsx
● Invalid form isn't submitted
expect(jest.fn()).not.toBeCalled()
Expected number of calls: 0
Received number of calls: 1

Answer (score 0):

try using .preventdefault() with an if else statement maybe? I'm not sure but this should stop the on click problem your having and if you use an if else statement you could add the code to stop the invalid email problem. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an open issue in JSDOM related to dependent react-testing-library: https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/729

But you can check for the most important validation errors in the submit handler, confirming that all the required values are passed or return early if they are missing.